# Loop through all worksheets in a work book, and change number stored as text to number

Tags: excel, vba

The code below loops through the worksheet, and changes the specified range to be a number format, and multiplies the range by a constant to remove the number stored as text format.

Problem I am having is that it is multiply the entire range by 1 which is leaving a trail of empty zeros after the range.

I tried creating a variable that finds the last row, but to no avail, the trailing zeros persist. I appreciate the assistance.

```
Sub copy_paste()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rConst As Range
Dim lrow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set rConst = Cells(40, 40)
rConst = 1

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "GA_AVERAGE" Then
        lrow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ws.Range("D1:F" & lrow).NumberFormat = "0"
        ws.Range("M1:N" & lrow).NumberFormat = "0"
        rConst.Copy

        ws.Range("D1:F" & lrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationMultiply
        ws.Range("M1:N" & lrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationMultiply


End If
    Next ws


rConst.Clear


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of using xlUp, try xlToLeft or xlToRight.

Comment: What is `rConst.Copy` supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = Workbooks("Book1") 'change to your workbook name

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "GA_AVERAGE" Then
            lrow = ws.Cells(ws.Cells.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
            Set rng = ws.Range("D1:F" & lrow & ", " & "M1:N" & lrow)
            rng.NumberFormat = "0"
            For Each cel In rng
                If cel.Value <> vbNullString Then cel.Value = cel.Value * 1
            Next
            Set rng = Nothing
        End If
    Next ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

/e: I'd suggest setting a workbook as well to make sure you refer to correst workbook and worksheet; edited the code

/e2: I see what you did here! Your method is a lot more efficient for big spreadsheets. Below is another way of doing it, which is ugly but works, all explained in comments. This method will keep existing zeros and convert them to numbers, and it won't create new unwanted zeros:

```
Sub test()
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tempStr As String, origVal As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wb = Workbooks("Book3") 'change to your workbook name
    tempStr = "tempStr"

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "GA_AVERAGE" Then
            lrow = ws.Cells(ws.Cells.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
            Set rng = ws.Range("D1:F" & lrow & ", " & "M1:N" & lrow)
            With rng
                'first, replace original blank cells with random string to keep them blank, otherwise they will appear as 0
                .Replace What:=vbNullString, Replacement:=tempStr
                'change format to number
                .NumberFormat = "0"
                'remember value to retrieve it later
                origVal = ws.Range("A1").Value
                'this is the value used for xlPasteSpecialOperationMultiply
                ws.Range("A1").Value = 1
                ws.Range("A1").Copy
                'multiply range by 1
                rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationMultiply
                'retrieve original value of A1
                ws.Range("A1").Value = origVal
                'retrieve original blank cells
                .Replace What:=tempStr, Replacement:=vbNullString
            End With
            tempStr = Empty
            origVal = Empty
            Set rng = Nothing
        End If
    Next ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

To find a last row with data on the spreadsheet you can use the code blow; it will error if spreadsheet is empty, replace `wb.Sheets(1)` to your wb and sheet

```
lrow = wb.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed Thanks Daniel